# Angular $http.post doesnt allow php script to execute gcc command on server

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a Php script, which works fine if I send data using a Simple HTML Form POST.
But when I tried to port the same code to Angular JS, I made the form data into JSON string and used $http.post to initiate a Post request to my Php script. Although I can see the Post data reaching the Php script, it returns nothing.

My aim is to run a C Language program which I send to the Php script using Angular $http.post

Any help will be appreciated. Also, I get no error, nothing in Php script and nothing in Chrome Console.

Here is the $http.post request that I am using :

```
var res = $http.post("/xyz/phpscript.php/", data);
        res.success(function(data, status) {
            // success
        });
        res.error(function(data, status) {
            // error
        });
```

Comment: How are you capturing the return of the php script? $http.post is an async operation and returns a promise. You can use its `then` or `success` method to pass a callback which will receive the data.

Comment: @VicenteGallurValero Yes I am using `success` method. And in my Php script I simply `echo` whatever I want to return.